# ESP8266 watchdog reset when using WiFi

Tags: embedded, iot, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I'm trying to use WiFi on a **ESP8266EX** based board (**XTVTX WEMOS D1 Mini Pro**).

The sketch is really simple.

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  WiFi.begin("<ssid>", "<password>");
}

void loop() {
  if ( WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.println("Connected");
  }
  else 
  {
    Serial.println("Not Connected");
  }

  yield();
}
```

The board keeps rebooting for a **watchdog reset** (source: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boards.html#rst-cause).

After a few seconds a fatal exception is raised (**28 = LoadProhibitedCause** - source: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exception_causes.html#exception-causes-exccause).

Here it is the log that shows the issue.

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)

wdt reset
load 0x4010f000, len 3424, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0x2e
load 0x3fff20b8, len 40, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0x2b
csum 0x2b
v00044b80
~ld
sp 0x3fffe9d0 
epc1=0x40204d1a, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x04000102, depc=0x00000000
Fatal exception (28): 
epc1=0x40001800, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00007ff0, depc=0x00000000
Fatal exception (28): 
epc1=0x40001800, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00007ff0, depc=0x00000000
Fatal exception (28): 
epc1=0x40001800, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00007ff0, depc=0x00000000
Fatal exception (28): 
epc1=0x40001800, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00007ff0, depc=0x00000000
Fatal exception (28): 
epc1=0x40001800, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00007ff0, depc=0x00000000
Fatal exception (28): 
epc1=0x40001800, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00007ff0, depc=0x00000000
Fatal exception (28): 
epc1=0x40001800, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00007ff0, depc=0x00000000
Fatal exception (28): 
epc1=0x40001800, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00007ff0, depc=0x00000000
[...]
```

My setup:

- **Power:** USB 3.0 powered hub (5V 500mA)
- **IDE:** Arduino IDE v2.0.4 on Linux
- **Library:** *esp8266* from *ESP8266 Community* v3.1.1 (tried also 3.1.0 and 3.0.2)
- Programmer settings:

  - **Board**: Generic ESP8266 Module
  - **Upload speed:** 115200
  - **Crystal Frequency:** 26MHz
  - **Flash Size:** 4MB (FS: none OTA: 1MB)
  - **CPU Frequency:** 80MHz
  - **MMU:** 32KB cache + 32 KB IRAM
  - **lwip variant:** v2 lower memory
  - **NONOS SDK:** nonos-sdk 2.2.1+100
  - **Erase flash:** all flash content
  - **Flash frequency:** 40MHz

Every other sketch which does not involve the use of WiFi is working without issues.

This sketch works fine on the **AzDelivery ESP8266MOD 12-F** board which is very similar.

The board is new and I've seen the WiFi working for a few seconds before entering in the boot loop.

Other people with the same behavior were using `#include <WiFi.h>` instead of `#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>`, so this is not my case.

I can't understand what is the problem. Has anyone faced this problem before and found a solution?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: the cause is insufficient powering or too high wifi consumption problem. https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/generic-class.html#setoutputpower

Comment: With `WiFi.setOutputPower(19.25);` works fine. Higher values raise the problem. Thank you!

Comment: this indicates problems with the antenna or garbage values in system area in flash where WiFi calibration should be stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Juraj (see comments below the question) the problem is the power consumption of this board.

I've modified the sketch in this way:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // >>>>>
  // set the maximum tx power (Values range from 0 to 20.5 [dBm] inclusive)
  WiFi.setOutputPower(19.25);
  // <<<<<

  WiFi.begin("<ssid>", "<password>");
}

void loop() {
  if ( WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.println("Connected");
  }
  else 
  {
    Serial.println("Not Connected");
  }

  yield();
}
```

When values higher than `19.25` are set, the board resets every time a connection with the AP is established.

See the documentation here https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/generic-class.html#setoutputpower.

Thanks to @Juraj for the quick support!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a while loop in setup() to wait until the WiFi connection is established

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin("<ssid>", "<password>");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Connected");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Not connected");
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```